# How to update a JAR file with a modfied Java file

Tags: jar

I have one JAR named as `abc.jar` with 15 class files. In JAR file I need to modify `xyz.class`, so I decompiled to `xyz.java` and modified it.

How can I update that JAR with the modified Java file? While trying to create (compile) the JAR file I am getting errors.

Comment: Which errors do you get, and how do you compile this ?

Comment: You compile the java files and bundle them in to a jar

Comment: Indeed. More details have to be provided. [Edit] them in the question please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your newly compiled class to the jar and overwrite the old one, here is how to add `xyz.class` and `xyz.java` to the jar :

```
jar uf abc.jar xyz.class xyz.java
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html) for more about updating a jar file.

Or simply you can use any archiving tool, like winrar to open and add files to the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the xyz.java and replace the xyz.class file directly in jar without building the jar again, if the single class has been modified.